# Do the functions have monotone on $\mathbb{R}$ a vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces, contest-math

> Denote by $E$ the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space of all mappings from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Rigorously justifying your answer in each case, indicate whether the following subsets of $E$ are vector subspaces of $E$.
>
> $$T=\{f \in E \text{ such that : $f$ is monotone on R } \}$$.

T is Vector subspace of E if and only if :

- $H\neq \emptyset$
- if $f,g \in T$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ then $(af+bg )\in T $

Indeed

- $0\mapsto 0\in T$
- and for $f,g\in T$ and $ \ \lambda\in \mathbb{R^*},\ \lambda f $ is monotone on $\mathbb{R}$
- and $f+g$ is monotone on $\mathbb{R}$

Then $T$ is subspace of $E$

Am i right ?

Comment: No. It doesn't work for $f+g$.

Comment: $e^x+e^{-x}$: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+exp%28x%29%2C+exp%28-x%29%2Cexp%28x%29%2Bexp%28-x%29

Comment: Is this really from a math competition?

Answer (score 1):

It does not work out for the third condition, $f+g$ is not necessarily monotone if f and g are monotone. Take for example $f(x) = x^3$ and $g(x) = -x$. Then you get $f(x) +g(x) = x^3 -x$ which is not monotone.